# Problem of metastability: simulation of dual port ram

Tags: ram, metastability

i simulate Dual Port Ram Register in VHDL and have some doubts about the metastability problem.

Dual Port Ram has 2 clock signal, one for Port A , the second for Port B. In my simulation I create two processes with 2 differentes clocks.

```
type memory_type is array(0 to adress_width) of std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);          --> memory array    
signal memory_sgnl : memory_type := (others => (others => '0'));;

begin

    -- Port A
    process(clk_a)
    begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then 
    if(rising_edge(clk_a)) then 
        if(we_a = '1') then
            memory_sgnl (addr_a) := data_in;
        end if;
        data_out<= memory_sgnl (addr_a);
    end if;
    end process;

    -- Port B
    process(clk_b)
    begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then 
    if(rising_edge(clk_b)) then 
        if(we_b = '1') then
            memory_sgnl (addr_b) := data_in;
        end if;
        data_out<= memory_sgnl (addr_b);
    end if;
    end process;
```

I have found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62009379/16107722). Mr Jim Lewis made a suggestion how DP Ram with 2 clocks can be simulated. He did the same implementation. So i can conclude I did correctly.

BUT I have read We need to solve a problem metastability, because there 2 clock signal : clock time crossing.

```
clk_crossing: process(clk, rst)
  begin
    if rst ='1' then
      --
      a_clk_b  <= '1';
      a_clk_bb <= '1';
      
      b_clk_b  <= '1';
      b_clk_bb <= '1';
             
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      a_clk_b   <= a_clk;
      a_clk_bb  <= a_clk_b;
     
      b_clk_b   <= b_clk;
      b_clk_bb  <= b_clk_b;
     
   end if; -- if rst ='1' then
 end process clk_crossing;
```

and then the processes should be `process(a_clk_bb  )` and `process(b_clk_bb  )`

Will be it correct? Did I understand correctly how to solve metastability question?

**EDIT 1**

The simulation of RAM is a "part" of SPI slave. SPI slave will send 8 bits vector data to RAM ( buffer of data). It has only one system clock and SPI clock + write_enb_signal ( FIFO is full and is ready to send data to RAM) . I thought Dual port RAm will work with system clk  and write_enb_signal.

```
process(clk_a)
    begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then 
      if(rising_edge(clk_a)) then 
...
```

in the simulation spi slave there is no additional clk signal for clk_a or clk_b...

Should I create one?

Comment: You never should put any user logic on clock path like that, especially on FPGAs. It's mentioned in Xilinx synthesis guide.

Comment: @MituRaj process(a_clk_bb  )?

Comment: The whole clk crossing process is an example for bad coding practice.

Comment: @MituRaj I have found it as an example for solving metastability problem...it was done for SPI and I2C in the similar way

Comment: @MituRaj Could Dual port ram be implemented with one clock? is it important to have different clk for ports?

Comment: I am afraid that's on data lines of SPI or I2C not a clock line. Your interpretation is wrong. You simply can't do what you did here.

Comment: Not at all necessary. You can use two synchronous clocks of different/same frequencies on both sides. And in that way there is no metastability concerns. Block rams are designed for synchronous operations only. However Xilinx has mentioned a work around in their Bram doc if you really want asynchronous clocking.

Comment: @MituRaj Smth like this : `if(rising_edge(clk_main)) then ` , the next line `if(rising_edge(clk_a)) then `.... Do I need main clk ( system clk)?

Comment: You have already accepted an answer and the edit has changed the question's nature. You should better be asking it as separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to implement dual port RAM, or indeed anything in FPGA, is to use one system clock, with different clock enables for the two ports.

You should never use two clocks, or events from an unsynchronised domain, unless there is **absolutely no alternative**, for instance one clock sourced by external equipment. Synchronise the async event as early as possible to the system clock.

Once you have two asynchronous clocks reaching the same logic, metastability is **unavoidable**. However it can be mitigated down to an insignificant likelihood by waiting long enough, which often requires pipelined latches, in the clock resolution logic.

[Matt Parker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ko3TdPy0TU) has the amusing concept of the ten.billion.human.second.century, which is about πx10<sup>19</sup> (28:50 in to save you watching the whole video). Once you have a chance of something occurring that's less likely than that, you can more or less assume you're not going to see it in your lifetime, and neither is anyone else. Once your metastability likelihood is less than that, some people would consider it 'solved'. But it depends on how fast your system is running, how many of them you've deployed, and what the penalty is for failure, whether you'd want a bigger number or could tolerate a smaller one. Being able to predict a failure probability though is hard. You need two points on the probability/wait_time curve, and even if the failure rate with no pipelined latches is measurable, it will often not be easily measurable with just one latch. People use increased clock rates, and carefully set up the input conditions to provoke failure, to make these measurements.

Comment: I have read about pipelined latches. The process "clk_crossing" is an implementation of it, isnt?

Comment: The clk_crossing process is using pipelined latches. So it's doing the right thing in order to minimise problems, but it's doing it in the wrong place. It's rather like commiting a murder, and then recycling the weapon in an eco-friendly way. You're doing the right eco thing, but in the commission of a heinous clk_crossing deed. Don't do the murder. Use a single clock for the RAM. Redesign for clock enables.

Comment: @LeeLeeYa You don't necessarily need pipelined latches to drive the probability of metastability down, you just have to wait long enough. However, if your system clock period is less than the time you need to wait, then you must use a pipeline of latches to implement the wait.

Comment: What you describe is not actually dual-port RAM (two control ports each with its own clock), but a dual-issue RAM (two control ports sharing a clock).  It may be useful for most of the same applications in practice, and easier to reason about... but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Also note that metastability also occurs in a single clock fully synchronous design, with some very-low probability which in many cases is still much higher than the target you mention.

Comment: Possibly you meant "The correct way to **instantiate** dual port RAM" and not "to implement", in which case I would agree with you.  And it would still not be an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @BenVoigt metastability shouldn't occur in a well-designed single clock fully synchronous design, not if the timing analyser uses min and max timings which go to sufficient sigma. Are you saying the timing data is not conservative enough? Instantiate, implement, whatever. The question asked should be unasked, the correct answer is don't do it that way.

Comment: @Neil_UK: "which go to sufficient sigma".  See, you do know it happens with a (very low) probability.  How many sigma do you think "ten.billion.human.second.century" is?